# Rally WSAPI not finding test case in test set

Tags: rally, code-rally, wsapi

After executing our test automation we are sending the results into Rally.  Here are the steps that we are following:

1. Create new Test Set
2. Add Test Case to Test set - The test case
   already exists in a test folder
3. Query for the test case within the test set - We added this additional read since we were receiving concurrency issues trying to immediately post results after adding the test case to the testset
4. Post the results to the testcase within the testset.

The issue we are running into is in step 3 above.  Sometimes, when a read is done to find the test case in the test set, it is unable to find it and so the results cannot be posted.

We have actually adjusted the code so it attempts 4 times with a 20 second delay between the third and 4th attempt and there are still several where results cannot be posted to Rally.

If anyone else has run into this issue and could provide guidance on a resolution that would be great

Comment: That's super weird.  Are you using one of our rest toolkits for communicating with wsapi?

Comment: Yes, we are using the rest toolkit.

Comment: Is this still happening?  There was a defect introduced recently (and fixed soon after) which could have caused this during the last week or so.  In general though, each instance of the rest api client should have server affinity (and shouldn't see these problems).  Are you using the same instance for all the requests?

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by this?  "each instance of the rest api client should have server affinity"

Comment: Each instance of rest api should maintain its cookies collection and so should then be "pinned" to the same app server node for all requests.  So you should be able to avoid the cache sync issues you appear to be having as long as you're not creating a new RallyRestApi for each request